# Passing value of option to max-attribute of input field

Tags: javascript, input, max, html-select

I have a select menu with a value in each option.

**The select menu looks like this:**

```
<select id="pa_tiefe" name="attribute_pa_tiefe" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_tiefe" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Tiefe</option>
<option value="25">bis 2,50 Meter</option>
<option value="30">2,51 - 3,00 Meter</option>
<option value="35">3,01 - 3,50 Meter</option>
<option value="40">3,51 - 4,00 Meter</option>
<option value="45">4,01 - 4,50 Meter</option>
</select>
```

Now I would like to pass the value in the option to an number-input-field in order to give this input-field a max value.

**The input field looks like this:**

```
<input type="number" name="ppom[fields][exakte_tiefe_in_cm]" id="exakte_tiefe_in_cm" class="ex-tiefe" autocomplete="off" data-type="number" value="" min="" max="">
```

I have a script with which I can pass the value of an option to the class of the input field.

**The function looks like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
var prevVal;
$("#pa_tiefe").on("change",function(){
  var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $(".ex-tiefe").removeClass(`${prevVal}`).addClass(`${val}`);
  prevVal = val;
});
</script>
```

How can I pass the value of an option to the max-attribute of the input-field instead of passing it to the class-attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Already found an answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
var prevVal;
$("#pa_tiefe").on("change",function(){
  var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
$(".ex-tiefe").attr('max', val);
  prevVal = val;
});
</script>
```